# Неправильное склонение даты создания вопроса

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Заметил, что в вопросе [Проблема с indexOf()](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/802155/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%81-indexof) есть проблема со склонением даты создания вопроса `1 года 3 месяца назад`.

Не должно ли здесь быть `задан: 1 год 3 месяца назад`?

> [image: фото]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://ru.traducir.win/string/4180

Был не тот перевод для формы с `one` для года. Отправил перевод:

> $years$ год $months$ месяца назад

После пересборки появится.

Comment: Появилось. Уже можно искать место, где надо наоборот)